# Android GC_CONCURRENT total heap size

Tags: android, heap-memory, logcat

First of all: I've used the search function, but nothing of the answers helped me out.

I have an algorithm from http://kociemba.org/cube.htm for solving a rubiks cube in java and I want to run it on an Android device (Samsung Galaxy S2 in this case). But when i run the function the App "freezes" and the LogCat shows frequently:

> GC_CONCURRENT freed 394K, 16% free 9600K/11335K, paused 12ms+12ms, total 60ms

This problem occurs if I want to create the following class:

```
CoordCube c = new CoordCube(cc);
```

I don't want to post the whole class of CoordCube, but there are a lot of static tables for the algorithmn. In the documentation of the algorithmn it is said that it needs 5 MB memory space.

So I think the total heap is too low.

*getMemoryClass()* returns 48 MB, so I wonder why the total heap size (according to the GC_CONCURRENT statement) is ~12MB. Thus there are very large static tables, there is no chance to reduce the memory use.

Is there any way to increase the heap size, so that i can create this class? I've tried *android::largeHeap="true"*, but nothing changed.

I hope anyone can help me! Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I let the program run without the debugger for a few minutes and it goes on. If I re-run the code, it runs less than a second. (Because of the static data I guess). So for the first time it takes very long to execute.

The used memory and total memory of the GC_CONCURRENT statement increases until it has finished. 
Any idea how to speed up this procedure?

Comment: If your app needs too much memory it will crash with an OutOfMemory error, but it don't seems to be the case. In my opinion, if it freeze it's because the UI-Thread is busy with too much non-UI-computation. So create a new Thread or an AsyncTask and create your CoordCube there instead of the main Thread.

Comment: sry. freeze is not a good expression here. If I debug the code gets stuck on creating the class (even on another thread). It doesn't even get to the constructor. I think it has to do with the heap size, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: *the code gets stuck* is not really a good expression too ;) . What do you see ? your debugger reach the `new CoordCube` but never reach the first line of the constructor ? In this case you can try to add some logs and not running the app in debug mode (sometimes the debugger slow down the app dramatically)

Comment: GC_CONCURRENT is a normal log when your App is running. On the other hand GC_FOR_ALLOC is more annoying and is often an indication that the heap is growing. In you log : 11335K is total heap. If this number doesn't change, then you probably don't a have any memory heap problem.

Comment: I've tried it without debugger now. The GC_CONCURRENT total heap size is increasing until 15751K. Then the LogCat says "GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 14% free 13635K/15751K, paused 37 ms". The Code never reaches the first line of the constructor. Even not with Logs and nodebugger.

Comment: EDIT: After ~3 minutes it continued! Do you have any idea why it is so slow? On the pc the code runs in less than a secon. Yeah i know that the system is much faster, but is there a way to make it faster?